# How to modify the browser title dynamically in DNN 9 Series

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Within DNN 9+, if we want an organization name followed by the page name in the browser tab, what would be the best way to dynamically incorporate this for multiple pages?

I've tried modifying the **DNN (DotNetNuke) 7/8/9 c# Compiled Theme package** through Visual Studio 2015, but no luck.  It appears that the templates only allow you do manage code between the body elements.  Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the page name consists of the Portal Name and Tab Name (Unless you have specified a Title in the Page Settings, then it's just the Title).

```
PortalSettings.PortalName + " - " + PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName;
```

So if you change the Portal Name, you will already get what you need.

If the Portal Name is not an option, you can change the title using javascript. Just add this snippet to the .ascx Skin File.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = "<%= "StackOverflow - " + PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName %>";
</script>
```

If you want to do it neatly for SEO purposes etc you will have to create your own Skin Object or Module.